Lead-acid battery charging circuit
"This schematic is for a lead-acid battery charger circuit. I've set up this circuit, but it's only charging at about 15 milliamps. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this problem? By the way, all component values are according to the schematic, except I used a 13-volt transformer instead of a 15-volt one."

I anticipated that the circuit would output an initial charging current of approximately 400 milliamps, which would subsequently taper off to 100 milliamps as the battery reached a full charge.

Alireza ganjeh - Hi, Where did that image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in the [tour] & [help])

Perhaps you state the problem yourself "except I used a 13-volt transformer instead of a 15-volt one" as 13V plus the losses won't give enough excess voltage to overcome the battery voltage. So change the transformer first for the correct one.

What is the voltage across C1?

@Alireza I'm a moderator. : Bad cop: If you do not do the following as as requested by a moderator 2 days ago your question WILL be deleted. You have logged in since the above message was posted. ||  GOOD COP: To comply with site rules you MUST provide a reference to where you got other material from. The diagram MAY come from https://www.electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/hardware-diy/12v-battery-charger-absorb-float . Please add a link to where you got it from. || I could have added that link but it may be wrong AND you are responsible for following site rules. ...

... We have ongoing problems with people failing to cite material from elsewhere and it is a legal requirement and one that moderators are obliged to enforce. || We have problems with people "lawyering" the fine detail of this and it would be a lot easier for all if people could help us by citing sourced material.

Try replacing the battery (temporarily :-) ) with a 10V zener diode (it will dissipate some Watts so power up only quickly) OR a 10 Ohm 10 Watt (5 Watt if quick) resistor. What current do you get? --> If it is much higher this (probably) shows that you do not have enough input voltage. || Add a new Alkaline battery* in series with the transformer supply to increase the voltage. What charge current do you get? Try adding two batteries in series. || *D best, C OK, AA probably OK briefly.
